# how to remove padding left UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I would like to use a **custom View**  as UIBarButtonItem left in an UINavigationController, is it possible to remove the left padding here?

Ill alrady tried:

```
let  btn = UIButton()
btn.frame = CGRect(x: -50, y: -50, width: 44, height: 50)
btn.setImage(UIImage(name:"img").withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openSetting), for: .touchUpInside)

let leftButtonBar = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btn)

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = ( [leftButtonBar , otherBtn ])
```

[image]

how to remove space left setting icon

**update**. tired this code:

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 
view.backgroundColor = .gray
let  btn = UIButton()
btn.frame = CGRect(x: -15, y: 0, width: 44, height: 50)
btn.setImage(UIImage(name:"img").withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(DashboardTabBarController.openSetting), for: .touchUpInside)
view.addSubview(btn)
let leftButtonBar = UIBarButtonItem(customView: view)
```

[image]

problem this user when clicked btn setting user
and other problem **title** navigation not **center align**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should have noticed that whatever `x` value you provide to your custom view i.e, `btn`, it will always start from the same position because internally navigation bar doesn't count for position provided for that item and it always set the internally defined position as in below image, I set the background color to the custom button for better visuals.

[image]

So, the trick here is to put your custom button into another container view as below,

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 50)))
view.backgroundColor = .green
let  btn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: -10, y: 10 , width: 30, height: 30))
btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "cancelled")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openSetting), for: .touchUpInside)
btn.backgroundColor = .yellow
btn.tintColor = .red
view.addSubview(btn)

let  btn2 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 10, width: 30, height: 30))
btn2.setImage(UIImage(named: "cancelled")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
btn2.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
btn2.tintColor = .yellow
btn2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openSetting), for: .touchUpInside)
view.addSubview(btn2)

let itemsContainer = UIBarButtonItem(customView: view)
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [itemsContainer]
```

This will result into this,

[image]

Now, if you change the `x`, `y`, `width`, `height` of `btn`, it will adjust accordingly.

Comment: Yes, this was just to explain the issue. You have to adjust the size/position according to your needs. Just one more note, you can set navigation title as a custom view also with the given frame to adjust its position incase you want to do in future.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this. It works fine for me. If this code not working properly then I will give you another solution.

```
   let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
    let  btn = UIButton()
    btn.frame = CGRect(x: -15, y: 0, width: 44, height: 50)
    btn.setImage(UIImage(name:"img").withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openSetting), for: .touchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(btn)
    let leftButtonBar = UIBarButtonItem(customView: view)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = ( [leftButtonBar])
```

Please add other button in View and set the width of view accordingy.It may hepls to you.Thank you

Comment: Custom Views means??

Comment: _UIBarButtonItem(customView: btn)_ yeh @sanjukta

Comment: thanks , It helped
But the problem did not resolve @sanjukta

Comment: Please share your problem.

Comment: Please set the view height to 64. Because the navigation bar + stratus bar height is 64. After that it may display in center

Comment: Please make sure your image is correct. Sometimes, poorly made icons have padding inside the image, so this might not be the problem of the BarButtonItem, but the image itself.

Comment: Even though the position is fixed, the tap area is still wrong (I cannot tap on the left size of the button) iOS 13.1

Answer (score 1):

You can set `imageInsets` and set image this is example of left margin to set back image on position of default back button

```
 let rightBtn = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "BackArrow"), style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(actnClose))
 rightBtn.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -12, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    
 self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(rightBtn, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the x value of cRect to zero:

```
btn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: -50, width: 44, height: 50)
```

Comment: I think the frame origin is ignored by UINavigationView, and it only uses the width/height.  I'm thinking he might have to include his button within a UIView and using that view to create the bar button item.  obviously making sure that view doesn't clip his button..

Comment: I tried it already but the user got into trouble clicking the button

Answer (score 0):

The less painful and actually cleanest solution was to hide the left button and just add a subview directly to the navigationBar and customise it's position and size with the good old constraints. Worked like a charm. Haven't tested it in every situation but seems to work fine.